# Blackberry QR Code Generator for .bar files

Tags: qr-code, blackberry-10

I have some BlackBerry apps that have been converted from Android apps. They are apps for work so dont want to be put onto the App World due to email addresses and private information. I was wondering if there is a QR code generator that will create a code for a .bar file so people can scan the code on their blackberry devices to get them onto their phone?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things worth noting here:

1) If these apps are intended for a corporate environment, they need to be deployed through the enterprise's corporate BES. Otherwise, they will not have access to the work perimeter.

2) However, Android apps can not run in the [work perimeter](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_playbook_balance.html).

3) If you create a QR code that points to the address of your app in the BlackBerry World web store, and the user scans it, it should open BlackBerry World to the correct page.

Comment: So they can be put onto devices through the corporate BES? Can we send it out to each device at the same time?

Comment: The BES admin decides if it's mandatory or optional. If it's optional the user goes into the enterprise BlackBerry World and downloads it when they want. If it's mandatory it gets pushed to the device. Again, Android apps are not supported in the work perimeter.